# Destination + Paste Special error VBA

Tags: vba

I am having an issue in my formula. Check the code Below.

```
With Worksheets("L.NAM.O")
        With .Cells.Find(What:="record ID", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("D35").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
        End With
    End With
```

In the destination, when you paste my values, I want it to be PasteSpecial Values, but this error is coming: "Run time error 1004: Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Range Class." Any ideas how to get it solved? Many Thanks!

Comment: Put the paste special destination as a separate command - `Copy Destination:=` only works with a basic copy.  So '.....Copy' and then 'Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("D35").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)`

Comment: It will also error if 'record id' isn't found.  Use a range variable to store the FIND result, and then check `If Not variable Is Nothing Then.... copy & paste`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you show me that in a code? I am not that good yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to paste values you could avoid `Copy()` method and just use `Value` property of `Range` object:

substitute:

```
.Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("D35").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

with:

```
With .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
    Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("D35").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: You user3598756 always saving me! haha. Thank you! This works exactly how I want. =)